# Change event handler and mutually exclusive radios

Tags: jquery

According to [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/), the change event handler fires when the value changes. What about with mutually exclusive radio buttons? Selecting one button would set one button to "unchecked" and another to "checked". Would the change event handler fire for both of these elements?

EDIT: Nevermind, I found the answer.

Comment: have you tried to test it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are two radio buttons with the same "name", you will only get one onChange event because only one field value is changing.

Answer (score 0):

It will fire for both, if you have event handlers on both radio buttons. But since they're mutually exclusive, you probably only need the listener on one of them, and get their states from that.

Answer (score 0):

The change event will only fire on the radio you "checked", and if you use attr('checked', 'checked') to set/unset the radio, it will not fire the change event.